# Why $('#id').val() not working while document.getElementById('id').value works perfect?

Tags: javascript, jquery

`$('#id').val() = $.cookie("name");` - not works, nothing changes

`document.getElementById('id').value = $.cookie("name");` - works fine

Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not directly accessing the elements value.  The left hand side of your expression is a getter which evaluates to a literal.  So the expression is comparable to something like `5 = 10`, which obviously cant work

```
$('#id').val() = $.cookie("name");
```

`val()` is overloaded, and by giving it an argument you can reassign

```
$('#id').val($.cookie("name"));
```

Comment: no problem.  the one in which you used the DOM method directly works bc `document.getElementById('id').value` is not a getter method, it is exactly that value as indicated by the lack of parens

Answer (score 4):

try to use

```
$('#id').val($.cookie("name"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the getter version of val() when you call it with no arguments.

Use `$('#id').val($.cookie("name"));` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#id').val($.cookie("name"));
```